# Creating an Ektron Smart Form Definition via the API

Tags: c#, api, ektron

I've been trying to create a smart form definition from another application. The app successfully creates the smart form, but I'm unable to get the FieldList, DisplayXSLT or Schema fields to populate.

This leaves me with a blank smart form definition (less that ideal).

Here's the code I have to perform the action. Any ideas?

```
// form is a simple POCO with values copied from an existing SmartForm Definition
var config = new SmartFormConfigurationData();

config.SmartformTitle = form.Name;            
config.SmartformDescription = form.Description;
config.XmlSchema = form.Schema;
config.PackageDisplayXslt = form.Xslt;
config.FieldList = form.FieldList;
config.Type = EkEnumeration.XmlConfigType.Content;

var api = new SmartFormConfigurationManager(ApiAccessMode.Admin);
api.RequestInformation.ServicesPath = this.EktronServiceHost;
api.RequestInformation.AuthenticationToken = this.GetAdminAuthToken();

api.Add(config);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I'm unable to get the FieldList, DisplayXSLT or Schema fields to populate" ? Also, how are you creating the "form" object?

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

I heard back from Ektron Support on this issue.  It's not so much a "bug" per-se... It's more a case of this API class looking very similar to the ContentManager but not behaving like it.  I expected that since it looked so similar to ContentManager and many of the other classes, I would be able to call `Add()` and it would just magically work.  It turns out the solution is a little more complicated.

**Adding a smartform is a two-step process:  first `Add()`, then `Update()`.**

The Add method doesn't set all of the fields and in fact passes in NULL for a few of the parameters on the stored procedure that creates the entry in `xml_collection_tbl`.

The real fun comes in step 2.  Basically, you start with the SmartForm's HTML -- the stuff you see when you're in the "Data Design" view for editing the smart form definition and you click that `<>` button ("HTML") at the bottom of the editor.  You run that through a whole bunch of XSLTs that are burried in the WorkArea folder to construct the missing fields, and then you call update.  Here's the code that worked for me:

```cs
var sfManager = new SmartFormConfigurationManager();
var data = sfManager.GetItem(12);

if (data == null) return;

var sfcData = new SmartFormConfigurationData();
sfcData.Type = EkEnumeration.XmlConfigType.Content;
sfcData.SmartformTitle = "SmartForm12 copy";
sfcData.SmartformDescription = "SmartForm12 copy";
sfcData.XmlSchema = "";
sfcData.PackageDisplayXslt = data.PackageDisplayXslt;
sfcData.FieldList = data.FieldList;
        
sfcData = sfManager.Add(sfcData);

Response.Write("SmartForm added with id: " + sfcData.Id);

var design = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/NewsArticleSmartForm.html"));
var contentApi = new ContentAPI();

var schema = contentApi.TransformXsltPackage(design, Server.MapPath("~/WorkArea/ContentDesigner/DesignToSchema.xslt"), true);
var fieldList = contentApi.TransformXsltPackage(design, Server.MapPath("~/WorkArea/ContentDesigner/DesignToFieldList.xslt"), true);
var viewEntryXslt = contentApi.TransformXsltPackage(design, Server.MapPath("~/WorkArea/ContentDesigner/DesignToEntryXSLT.xslt"), true);

var xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xsltArgs.AddParam("srcPath", "", "/WorkArea/ContentDesigner/");

var viewXsltSource = string.Concat("<root>", design, "<ektdesignpackage_list>", fieldList, "</ektdesignpackage_list></root>");
var viewXslt = contentApi.XSLTransform(viewXsltSource, Server.MapPath("~/WorkArea/ContentDesigner/DesignToViewXSLT.xslt"), true, false, xsltArgs, false);
var initialDocument = contentApi.TransformXsltPackage(design, Server.MapPath("~/WorkArea/ContentDesigner/PresentationToData.xslt"), true);

var sbPackage = new StringBuilder("<ektdesignpackage_forms><ektdesignpackage_form><ektdesignpackage_designs><ektdesignpackage_design>");
sbPackage.Append(design);
sbPackage.Append("</ektdesignpackage_design></ektdesignpackage_designs><ektdesignpackage_schemas><ektdesignpackage_schema>");
sbPackage.Append(schema);
sbPackage.Append("</ektdesignpackage_schema></ektdesignpackage_schemas><ektdesignpackage_lists><ektdesignpackage_list>");
sbPackage.Append(fieldList);
sbPackage.Append("</ektdesignpackage_list></ektdesignpackage_lists><ektdesignpackage_views><ektdesignpackage_view>");
sbPackage.Append(viewEntryXslt);
sbPackage.Append("</ektdesignpackage_view><ektdesignpackage_view>");
sbPackage.Append(viewXslt);
sbPackage.Append("</ektdesignpackage_view></ektdesignpackage_views><ektdesignpackage_initialDocuments><ektdesignpackage_initialDocument>");
sbPackage.Append(initialDocument);
sbPackage.Append("</ektdesignpackage_initialDocument></ektdesignpackage_initialDocuments></ektdesignpackage_form></ektdesignpackage_forms>");

sfcData.PackageXslt = sbPackage.ToString();
sfcData.FieldList = fieldList;

var baseFilename = "SmartForm" + sfcData.Id;
var schemaFilename = "/" + baseFilename + "Schema.xsd";
var xsltFilename = "/" + baseFilename + "Xslt.xslt";

sfcData.XmlSchema = schemaFilename;  // The file will be prefixed with /XmlFiles
        
var unPackDisplayXslt = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"><xsl:output method=\"xml\" version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" indent=\"yes\"/><xsl:template match=\"/\"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test=\"ektdesignpackage_forms/ektdesignpackage_form[1]/ektdesignpackage_views/ektdesignpackage_view[2]\"><xsl:copy-of select=\"ektdesignpackage_forms/ektdesignpackage_form[1]/ektdesignpackage_views/ektdesignpackage_view[2]/node()\"/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select=\"ektdesignpackage_forms/ektdesignpackage_form[1]/ektdesignpackage_views/ektdesignpackage_view[1]/node()\"/></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";

var displayXslt = contentApi.TransformXsltPackage(sbPackage.ToString(), unPackDisplayXslt, false);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles" + xsltFilename), displayXslt);

sfcData.Xslt1 = xsltFilename;  // The file will be prefixed with /XmlFiles
sfcData.DefaultXslt = 1;

sfManager.Update(sfcData);
```

I extracted the HTML for my existing smart form and saved in the root of my site as NewsArticleSmartForm.html.  Here's what my file looked like:

```html
<p>Author:&#160;<input type="text" name="Author" id="Author" ektdesignns_caption="Author" ektdesignns_name="Author" title="Author" ektdesignns_indexed="false" ektdesignns_nodetype="element" size="24" class="design_textfield" /></p>
<p>&#160;</p>
<p>Article Summary:&#160;<textarea name="Summary" id="Summary" ektdesignns_caption="Summary" ektdesignns_name="Summary" title="Summary" ektdesignns_indexed="false" ektdesignns_nodetype="element" cols="40" rows="3" class="design_textfield"></textarea>
</p>
<p>&#160;</p>
<p>Article Body:</p>
<p>&#160;</p>
<ektdesignns_richarea id="Body" name="Body" ektdesignns_caption="Body" ektdesignns_name="Body" title="Body" ektdesignns_indexed="false" ektdesignns_nodetype="element">&#160;</ektdesignns_richarea>
<p>&#160;</p>
```

Good luck!

#### Original Answer:

Creating a copy of a SmartForm configuration should be fairly straight-forward.  The `SmartFormConfigurationData` object has a `Clone()` method on it which makes it really easy to create a copy of an existing SmartForm.  I say "should be" because it doesn't work.

I had an answer all typed out ready to post; I tried some code and it appeared to work.  The new smartform was listed in the workarea, but when I clicked on that new smartform to view its details, I realized something was wrong.

I tried the following code:

```cs
var sfManager = new SmartFormConfigurationManager();
var config = sfManager.GetItem(7);

if (config == null) return;

var newSmartForm = config.Clone();
newSmartForm.SmartformTitle += " copy";

sfManager.Add(newSmartForm);
```

Here are the details from the original smartform:
[image: original smartform, properties tab] [image: original smartform, Display Information tab]

And here's what the new smartform looked like -- the one I created with the frameworkAPI:
[image: api-generated smartform, properties tab] [image: api-generated smartform, Display Information tab]

I did find one API method that successfully created a copy of an existing smartform:

```cs
var sfApi = new Ektron.Cms.ContentAPI();
var newId = sfApi.ReplicateXmlConfiguration(7, "copied sf title");
```

The problem with that method is that the smartform must exist on your system and you can only change the title.  So, I went digging into the database to see what was happening.  It turns out that after calling this `ReplicateXmlConfiguration()` method, the two database records are identical (except for the expected LastUpdated type of fields).

[image: source and target database records after calling ReplicateXmlConfiguration()]

After calling the frameworkAPI's `Update()` method (same holds true when calling `Add()`), the "updated" record is clearly different.

[image: source and target database records after calling Update() in framework api]

I think we've got a genuine bug here.  This happens both in v8.7 sp2 and v9.0 sp1.  I've opened a case with Ektron support, and I'll update my answer as I hear back.  They have always been very responsive when I've dealt with them in the past.